# Display all child items of all parent items in a single view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am currently using a view model to display a list of Parents (Artists) in an Index view, that includes an ActionLink that redirects to Index/5 to show a list of children (Albums), while still showing the full list of parents.

I am now trying to update this so that on routing to Index, all of the children will be loaded for every parent, which I imagine includes using a nested @foreach.

It seems like it should be simple and I am trying to keep this example as simple as possible (avoiding partial views etc.), but I haven't been able to find a comparative tutorial or answered question anywhere - (this could well be that I am searching for the wrong terms!).

Any help on whether I am going about this the right way would be much appreciated.

The controller

```
    // GET: /ArtistsTest/

    public ActionResult Index(Int32? id)
    {
        var viewModel = new TestViewModel();
        viewModel.Artists = db.Artists
            .Include(a => a.Albums);

        if (id != null)
        {
            ViewBag.ArtistID = id.Value;
            viewModel.Albums = viewModel.Artists.Where(a => a.ArtistID == id.Value).Single().Albums;
        }

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

The view:

```
@foreach (var artist in Model.Artists)
{
    <p>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => artist.ArtistID)
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => artist.ArtistName)
        @Html.ActionLink("Select", "Index", new { id = artist.ArtistID })
    </p>
}
<br />
@if (Model.Albums != null)
{
    <p>
        Albums:
        @foreach (var album in Model.Albums)
        {
            <p>
                @Html.DisplayFor(albumItem => album.AlbumName)
            </p>  
        }
    </p>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View:

```
@foreach (var artist in Model.Artists)
{
    <p>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => artist.ArtistID)
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => artist.ArtistName)
        @Html.ActionLink("Select", "Index", new { id = artist.ArtistID })

        @foreach(var album in artist.Albums){
            <p>
                @Html.DisplayFor(albumItem => album.AlbumName)
            </p>  
        }
    </p>
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var viewModel = new TestViewModel();
    viewModel.Artists = db.Artists.Include(a => a.Albums);

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Comment: That's perfect. Very much appreciated.